# iPhone 4S speaks items on the screen

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4S and I was looking at the photos in my album when it suddenly started speaking all the commands. How do I disable this?

Comment: What might "taking all the commands" involve? Does it normally ignore your commands or perhaps something else we can help clarify?

Comment: did you accidentally active the voice control?

Answer (score 4):

In your settings, check `General -> Accessibility -> VoiceOver`, and see if this feature is on. I suspect that it is. Turn it off, and it should stop speaking all of the commands.